# Is it possible to add a role to a discord user using PHP or web only?

Tags: php, discord, discord.js, webhooks

I was wondering if a user provides me with their discord username eg. `user#0001`. Can I assign it a role in my server with the ID `123456789` using PHP or webhooks? I know I can send messages with webooks, but I am unsure of how I can add a role to a user. There isn't much documentation on discord webhooks.

Comment: well, i think i can't get your point clearly. can you give out a code and tell us the concrete problem?

Comment: You cannot do that with Webhooks, let's get that out of the way. You cannot do that with just PHP either. The only way to do this is to have a Discord bot in the same guild as the user and create an API endpoint (preferably using [express](https://expressjs.com/)). You can then send a request to that endpoint and let your bot handle the rest. Or, you can use the [Discord API](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#add-guild-member-role) directly, but you'll still need a Bot account.

Comment: @Jakye Is there any way to do with only a shared web hosting (where we don't have access to a VPS)

Comment: @Jakye Also can a discord bot in js run as a normal javascript script, like they do on websites?

Comment: Express will, most likely, work on shared web hosting, so you don't need to worry.
A Discord bot will work in a browser as you said, only if you use the [web build](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/topics/web). I still recommend that you should go with Node.

Comment: @Jakye Are there any good tutorials on express for discord? I have no experience in .js or with discord bot in js. I know know in python how to make discord bots

Comment: @Jakye is Node.js and express the same thing?

Comment: No, express is a framework for Node.js that lets you create your own website in Node. I usually use it only for creating APIs. There are a lot of tutorials for express.